# styled-components CSS are not applied in NextJS 13

Tags: reactjs, next.js, styled-components

I am using NextJs (version 13.4.10) and styled-components (version 6.0.4) in my project. When I run the project for the first time(npm run dev), all the styles are applied as well, but if I make a change in my code and re-render it, the styles no longer work.

There is my code here:

```
"use client";
import React from "react";
import Image from "next/image";
import { BannerWrapper, ImageBannerWrapper, BannerTitle } from "./style";

export default function Banner() {
  return (
    <>
      <ImageBannerWrapper className="absolute flex">
        <Image
          src="/images/banner/Mask-banner.png"
          height={709}
          width={747}
          alt="banner"
        />
        <BannerTitle className="font-primary text-9xl text-white text-left font-normal">
          <span className="font-primary text-9xl text-white text-left font-semibold">
            Let us guide you to the best choice.
          </span>
        </BannerTitle>
      </ImageBannerWrapper>
      <BannerWrapper className="flex items-center bg-default -mt-16" />
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer to my question in the [documentation of NextJs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/styling/css-in-js).

Since I am using styled-component, I should be Configuring CSS-in-JS as a three-step:

> - A style registry to collect all CSS rules in a render.
> - The new useServerInsertedHTML hook to inject rules before any content that might use them.
> - A Client Component that wraps your app with the style registry during initial server-side rendering.

**create a new registry:**

```
'use client' 
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { useServerInsertedHTML } from 'next/navigation'
import { StyleRegistry, createStyleRegistry } from 'styled-jsx'
 
export default function StyledJsxRegistry({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  // Only create stylesheet once with lazy initial state
  // x-ref: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#lazy-initial-state
  const [jsxStyleRegistry] = useState(() => createStyleRegistry())
 
  useServerInsertedHTML(() => {
    const styles = jsxStyleRegistry.styles()
    jsxStyleRegistry.flush()
    return <>{styles}</>
  })
 
  return <StyleRegistry registry={jsxStyleRegistry}>{children}</StyleRegistry>
}
```

**Then, wrap your root layout with the registry:**

```
import StyledJsxRegistry from './registry'
 
export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  return (
    <html>
      <body>
        <StyledJsxRegistry>{children}</StyledJsxRegistry>
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```